# How to recite the AdityaHrudaya Stotram

Tags: mantras, stotra, surya

I have a small doubt. The Adityahrudaya stotram in Valmiki Ramayana has 2 versions [as available here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_navagraha/adityahriday.html).

1st is having the standard shlokas while the 2nd one is having the Nyasas and Names of Rishis etc.
Which Stotra should be chanted?

The stotra is also called as Adityahrudaya mantra and also has various beejakshari mantras in the 2nd version but this stotra is present in an Itihasa. So can anyone regardless of being initiated chant this stotra? If not, then which version should we chant?

Comment: Thank you @Rāmachandra ji that you yourself came to answer my question. 

Comment: Ji pls pardon me for giving wrong advice earlier.Consulted some resources and came to the conclusion If not initiated pls follow the stotra(from the same website) till "cha viniyogaha" and skip the Nyasas(all of them) and continue with hymns....

Comment: Ohh..Thanks again for giving your time on this. Btw, can I chant the 1st one sometimes if I wish? Also, one more doubt..You said to read till 'cha viniyogah' but those sentences also contain 'om' in them. So can then also uninitiated people can read those sentences? @Rāmachandra ji

Comment: Sir actually if you read carefully the first and the second part are same(i mean the hymns)except for Viniyoga and Nyasas in the second one.As its a stotram,part of Itihasa and not a vedic mantra so yes you can chant it.Also reason for not skipping the viniyoga(application of stotram for certain purpose) is because it makes the stotra "kunthita"(originally listed as one of the flaws of mantra sadhana)literally meaning dull/blunt.Only if we have clarity in our mind and speech why are we chanting the stotra that we can expect to benefit from the cosmic energy around us.

Comment: Reason why i asked to skip Nyasas was i couldn't find any credible sources to support if they are indeed the correct ones or not, as Nyasas vary from mantra to mantra and stotram to stotram and need to be accurate to give specific results....

Comment: Every stotram mentions a Seer(sage),Devata(deity) of the Stotram,Chanda(Vedic meter),Shakti(Energy),Kilaka(Lock) and Viniyoga(Purpose of Application).Without these present the power of stotrams cannot be harnessed.
Eg: For Rama Raksha stotram we have Budhakoushika(Vishwamitra) Rishi as the seer which establishes its authenticity, Sri Rama as the devata, Chanda as Anushtubh, Shakti as Sita Devi, Lord Hanuman who performs utakilana(unlocking) of the stotram and and purpose of application is seeking blessings in the form of protection by Lord Shri Rama(viniyogaha)!
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a Lot! I thought that only mantras have Viniyoga, Kilaka, Shakti, etc. But now it seems that stotras also have it. But do all stotras have it as I've not seen these for many stotras

Comment: But Viniyog should not make the stotra 'kunthita'. Why did you write that viniyoga makes a stotra kunthita? i guess it's a typo isn't it? @Rāmachandra ji

Comment: My bad Sir without chanting viniyogaha,(if mentioned and purposefully avoided) stotra becomes 'kunthita'. Also not every stotra is used for specific purpose like  eg:protection(like kavachams and raksha stotrams),victory over enemies,gain of wealth etc.You can check out some stotras that are used for various purposes [here](https://www.celextel.org/search/?words=Viniyoga) if interested.Also Sir pls don't refer to me with 'ji' i am unworthy of such respect, i am very much young in my early 20's and just a humble sadhaka who has just embarked on his journey of discovering his own Truth !